# How do I pass a method as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass a method as a parameter to a method?

```
self.method2(self.method1)

def method1(self):
    return 'hello world'

def method2(self, methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun.call()
    return result
```

Comment: As noted in the answers here, using a method is not really different from using a plain function; I closed this as a duplicate of the best canonical I've been able to find, where I've added my own answer and given an example using methods.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Yes it is, just use the name of the method, as you have written. Methods and functions are objects in Python, just like anything else, and you can pass them around the way you do variables. In fact, you can think about a method (or function) as a variable whose value is the actual callable code object.

Since you asked about methods, I'm using methods in the following examples, but note that everything below applies identically to functions (except without the `self` parameter).

To call a passed method or function, you just use the name it's bound to in the same way you would use the method's (or function's) regular name:

```
def method1(self):
    return 'hello world'

def method2(self, methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun()
    return result

obj.method2(obj.method1)
```

Note: I believe a `__call__()` method does exist, i.e. you *could* technically do `methodToRun.__call__()`, but you probably should never do so explicitly. `__call__()` is meant to be implemented, not to be invoked from your own code.

If you wanted `method1` to be called with arguments, then things get a little bit more complicated. `method2` has to be written with a bit of information about how to pass arguments to `method1`, and it needs to get values for those arguments from somewhere. For instance, if `method1` is supposed to take one argument:

```
def method1(self, spam):
    return 'hello ' + str(spam)
```

then you could write `method2` to call it with one argument that gets passed in:

```
def method2(self, methodToRun, spam_value):
    return methodToRun(spam_value)
```

or with an argument that it computes itself:

```
def method2(self, methodToRun):
    spam_value = compute_some_value()
    return methodToRun(spam_value)
```

You can expand this to other combinations of values passed in and values computed, like

```
def method1(self, spam, ham):
    return 'hello ' + str(spam) + ' and ' + str(ham)

def method2(self, methodToRun, ham_value):
    spam_value = compute_some_value()
    return methodToRun(spam_value, ham_value)
```

or even with keyword arguments

```
def method2(self, methodToRun, ham_value):
    spam_value = compute_some_value()
    return methodToRun(spam_value, ham=ham_value)
```

If you don't know, when writing `method2`, what arguments `methodToRun` is going to take, you can also use argument unpacking to call it in a generic way:

```
def method1(self, spam, ham):
    return 'hello ' + str(spam) + ' and ' + str(ham)

def method2(self, methodToRun, positional_arguments, keyword_arguments):
    return methodToRun(*positional_arguments, **keyword_arguments)

obj.method2(obj.method1, ['spam'], {'ham': 'ham'})
```

In this case `positional_arguments` needs to be a list or tuple or similar, and `keyword_arguments` is a dict or similar. In `method2` you can modify `positional_arguments` and `keyword_arguments` (e.g. to add or remove certain arguments or change the values) before you call `method1`.

Comment: I'm confused by your apparent conflation of the word `method` with `function`. `def method1(spam):` is a function definition, not a method definition.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Yes, as far as I remember I was using "method" to be consistent with the terminology used in the question, even though these are technically functions. I thought the difference between methods and functions would be a distraction from the main point I was trying to make. Though I suppose I _could_ clear that up with an edit... I'm not sure if it's worth it though.

Comment: You answered a different question than was asked. OP asked if you could pass a method as a parameter e.g. `func(obj.method)`. You explained how to pass a function as a parameter e.g. `func(other_func)`, but while referring to functions as methods. I found this very confusing.

Comment: @MichaelDorst Oh, I see what you mean. I didn't realize someone would get hung up on the method/function distinction that much. Let me make a clarifying edit.

Answer (score 42):

Yes it is possible. Just call it:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method1(self):
        pass
    def method2(self, method):
        return method()

foo = Foo()
foo.method2(foo.method1)
```

Comment: what if there's no instance `foo`?

Comment: Then you simply not need foo, e.g.:
    `def method1():  
        pass  
    def method2(method)  
        return method()  
      
    method2(method1)`

Answer (score 17):

Use a `lambda` function. 
So if you have no arguments, things become pretty trivial:

```
def method1():
    return 'hello world'

def method2(methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun()
    return result

method2(method1)
```

But say you have one (or more) arguments in `method1`:

```
def method1(param):
    return 'hello ' + str(param)

def method2(methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun()
    return result
```

Then you can simply invoke `method2` as `method2(lambda: method1('world'))`.

```
method2(lambda: method1('world'))
>>> hello world
method2(lambda: method1('reader'))
>>> hello reader
```

I find this much cleaner than the other answers mentioned here.

Comment: If this were a value in a dictionary, how could I execute it rather than returning a function object? Edit: Just realized I can just put `()` at the end of the object in my return call, duh.

Comment: You can pass arguments by value or reference, but in case of a function, LAMBDA is definitely the way to go for function arguments

Answer (score 16):

Here is your example re-written to show a stand-alone working example:

```
class Test:
    def method1(self):
        return 'hello world'

    def method2(self, methodToRun):
        result = methodToRun()
        return result

    def method3(self):
        return self.method2(self.method1)

test = Test()

print test.method3()
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to pass a method of a class as an argument but don't yet have the object on which you are going to call it, you can simply pass the object once you have it as the first argument (i.e. the "self" argument).

```
class FooBar:

    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def foo(self, name):
        print "%s %s" % (self.prefix, name)


def bar(some_method):
    foobar = FooBar("Hello")
    some_method(foobar, "World")

bar(FooBar.foo)
```

This will print "Hello World"

Answer (score 8):

Yes; functions (and methods) are first class objects in Python. The following works:

```
def foo(f):
    print "Running parameter f()."
    f()

def bar():
    print "In bar()."

foo(bar)
```

Outputs:

```
Running parameter f().
In bar().
```

These sorts of questions are trivial to answer using the Python interpreter or, for more features, the [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) shell.

Answer (score 4):

Methods are objects like any other. So you can pass them around, store them in lists and dicts, do whatever you like with them. The special thing about them is they are callable objects so you can invoke `__call__` on them. `__call__` gets called automatically when you invoke the method with or without arguments so you just need to write `methodToRun()`.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly what you want, but a related useful tool is `getattr()`, to use method's name as a parameter.

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
      pass
   def MyMethod(self):
      print("Method ran")

# Create an object
object = MyClass()
# Get all the methods of a class
method_list = [func for func in dir(MyClass) if callable(getattr(MyClass, func))]
# You can use any of the methods in method_list
# "MyMethod" is the one we want to use right now

# This is the same as running "object.MyMethod()"
getattr(object,'MyMethod')()
```

Answer (score 3):

Example: a simple function call wrapper:

```
def measure_cpu_time(f, *args):
    t_start = time.process_time()
    ret = f(*args)
    t_end = time.process_time()
    return t_end - t_start, ret
```