# Passing a method in python

Tags: python

I am having problems passing a method in a function.  I have already looked at this previous post.

[How do I pass a method as a parameter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python)

Here is a simple example of what I tried.

```
def passMethod(obj, method):
    return obj.method()

passMethod('Hi', lower)
```

In the end I will use this to help write a function dealing with GIS (Geographic Information Systems) data. The data is like an array.  I want to add a new column NAME1 to the array.  The array then has a method to call the column array.NAME1.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Are you familiar with `map`?  And maybe a little `__iter__`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to pass a method around in this manner (though there are legitimate use-cases, some context for why you want this would be nice).  If you're unfamiliar with python, you might not realize you can just pass around `'Hi'.lower`.  This will give you a callable object that returns `'hi'`.

Comment: @Darthfett I tried to provide some context in the last paragraph; but in the abstract it is hard to understand. Basically, I have an object that has methods relating to variable names in a dataset. I want to write a function that allows users to choose the variable, and hence the method that is needed. Thus I cannot hardcode the method into my function; e.g., using 'Hi'.lower is insufficient because sometimes the variable might be called upper, or even foo.

Comment: @AlexOlssen I'm still a little unsure of exactly what you need.  The [attrgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) function provided by the operator module *may* be useful for your scenario, if using `getattr` can't do everything you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you give the name `lower`, that means to look up the name `lower` in the global namespace. It isn't there, because you're looking for the `lower` method of strings (the `str` class). That is spelled `str.lower`.

Then, in your function, `obj.method` means to look up the `method` attribute of the `obj`. It has nothing to do with the parameter named `method`, and cannot work that way. Instead, since you have an unbound method, pass the object as the `self` parameter explicitly: thus, `method(obj)`. That gives us:

```
def passMethod(obj, method):
    return method(obj)

passMethod('Hi', str.lower)
```

Alternately, we could use a string as the name of the method to look up on the passed-in object. That looks like:

```
def passMethod(obj, method):
    return getattr(obj, method)()

passMethod('Hi', 'lower')
```

Comment: The first two lines of code in [this article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm) are equivalent: `value = obj.attribute`
`value = getattr(obj, "attribute")`.  I think that should give you an idea of what the second example looks like without the `passMethod` function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but it makes more sense to pass the method name as a string:

```
def passMethod(obj, method_name):
    return getattr(obj, method_name)()

passMethod('Hi', 'lower')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first problem is that you're invoking the method before you return it.  Instead of returning obj.method() just return obj.method.

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print 'foobar!'

def pass_bar(obj):
    return obj.bar

f = Foo()
method = pass_bar(f)
method() # prints 'foobar!'
```

The other question is what exactly you're passing in to tell the code which method you want.  A string maybe?  If so, try something like

```
def pass_method(obj, method_name):
    return getattr(method_name)
```