# Compare two small directed graphs with attributes on edges and nodes

Tags: python, compare, diff, igraph

I want to compare two smaller directed python-igraph graphs, including all attributes and their values on edges or nodes and direction of edges. Is there any such function in the python-igraph package?

I saw [G1.isomorphic(G2)](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#isomorphic) and related, but they don't seem to work with attributes, nor with directionality of edges

Example:

```
import igraph as ig
G1=ig.Graph(directed=True)
G2=ig.Graph(directed=True)
G1.add_vertices(2)
G2.add_vertices(2)
G1.vs[0]['gaga'] = 'gugu'
G2.vs[0]['gaga'] = 'gogo'
G1.add_edge(0,1)
G2.add_edge(1,0)

print G1.isomorphic_vf2(G2)
>>>True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass custom comparing functions to the method `isomorphic_vf2` with the `node_compat_fn` and `edge_compat_fn` arguments. From the [docs](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#isomorphic_vf2):

> node_compat_fn - a function that receives the two graphs and two node indices (one from the first graph, one from the second graph) and returns True if the nodes given by the two indices are compatible (i.e. they could be matched to each other) or False otherwise. This can be used to restrict the set of isomorphisms based on node-specific criteria that are too complicated to be represented by node color vectors (i.e. the color1 and color2 parameters). None means that every node is compatible with every other node.

and

> edge_compat_fn - a function that receives the two graphs and two edge indices (one from the first graph, one from the second graph) and returns True if the edges given by the two indices are compatible (i.e. they could be matched to each other) or False otherwise. This can be used to restrict the set of isomorphisms based on edge-specific criteria that are too complicated to be represented by edge color vectors (i.e. the edge_color1 and edge_color2 parameters). None means that every edge is compatible with every other node.

Example:

```
import igraph as ig
G1=ig.Graph(directed=True)
G2=ig.Graph(directed=True)
G1.add_vertices(2)
G2.add_vertices(2)
G1.vs[0]['gaga'] = 'gugu'
G2.vs[0]['gaga'] = 'gogo'
G1.add_edge(0,1)
G2.add_edge(1,0)

print G1.isomorphic_vf2(G2)

def cmp_nodes(g1, g2, i1, i2):
    return g1.vs[i1]['gaga'] == g2.vs[i2]['gaga']

print G1.isomorphic_vf2(G2, node_compat_fn=cmp_nodes)
```

[Here is the included unit-test of this exact feature.](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/igraph/test/isomorphism.py)

Comment: Yes I read that. It says I can compare one node pair and/or edge pair of each graph. Fact  is I need to compare all nodes and all edges of the two graphs.

Comment: I added an example which hopefully explains it better. The compare function is called with graph1 and graph2, and the indices of *some* pair of vertices. This function is called many times for many different pairs of vertices until the algorithm is finished. It exists to allow you to compare attributes on your nodes. You can create a similar function for edges if needed.

Comment: ok, that seems to return the results I was looking for. Would you mind explaining how the function ```cmp_nodes``` can be called as argument in the ```isomorphic_vf2``` function and on top of that , also without its own arguments?

Comment: Of course. With the notation `node_compat_fn=cmp_nodes` we pass a handle to the function `cmp_nodes`, and bind it to the argument `node_compat_fn`. This means that inside `isomorphic_vf2` the `cmp_nodes` function can be called by writing `node_compat_fn(g1, g2, v1, v2)`. It is up to the programmer/code to ensure that the function is then called correctly. There is a minimal example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python

Comment: Should the example be the following?
`return g1.vs['gaga'][i1] == g2.vs['gaga'][i2]` i.e. with the index *after* the attribute name, since its a dictionary of lists.

Comment: @afaulconbridge The unittests still do it this way, so I assume it's still valid: https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/316fa6b3b42e348561b8b199338422841aceeb3c/tests/test_isomorphism.py#L6