# Compare nodes in 2 graphs igraph R

Tags: r, nodes, igraph, vertices

I'm using `igraph` in `RSudio` & have 2 directed weighted graphs (A & B) & all I want is to find, if it exists, is the list of shared nodes.

i.e. V(A) conjunct V(B)

```
A: 117->55  119->55  119->119 119->127 55 ->117 55 ->119 59 ->119 123->23  23 ->119 127->123 127->119 127->127 127->89 

B: 21 ->55  51 ->119 117->53  117->119 119->53  119->127 119->119 119->80  55 ->119 123->21  127->123 127->119 53 ->117
```

I found [this answer in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34189502/3595907) but the docs for [isomorphic.vf2](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Isomorphism.html) are too opaque for me, so I haven't found an equivalent procedure in `R`

I tried,

```
intersect(V(A), V(B))
```

But just get,

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I was expecting the set of shared node labels.

Comment: Please share the data using `dput()`, then we can help you on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try `names`, e.g.,

```
intersect(names(V(A)),names(V(B)))
```

or

```
V(graph.intersection(A, B, keep.all.vertices = FALSE))
```