# Python - use functions from another module in a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, parameter-passing

How do I use a function or set of functions from another module as a parameter in my own function I'm defining?

I'm trying to write a function that compares one vector `q` and calculates its distance from each vector in a set of vectors `x`. The function `get_distances` should take the one vector `q`, the set of vectors `x`, and a parameter `dist_method`. `dist_method` is supposed to take any one of the distance calculations from scipy.spatial.distance and use that for the calculation, so I could call the function something like this: `distances = get_distances(q, x, 'euclidean')` Here's the scipy reference page - `get_distances` should be able to take any of the distance functions braycurtis, canberra, ... , sqeuclidean, wminkowski:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

At the top of the `file1.py` file where this function is located, I've imported scipy.spatial.distance, from which I thought I should have access to functions to use just like distance.euclidean(), but when I call `get_distances` in the interpreter, I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dist_method'`.

I found a lot of answers already like the below that say functions are 'first-class objects' and that I should be able to use them as arguments just like any other argument, and I've tried using the **kwargs concept, but I can't put it all together.

- [Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python)
- [How do I pass a method as a parameter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python)
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing?

KNN.py:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance as dist

def get_distances(q, x, dist_method='euclidean', *args, **kwargs):
    """Query dataset to get distances for KNN

    Given a numpy array of vectors x and
    query point q, use dist_method to calculate
    distance from q to each vector in x

    Parameters:
        q: tuple
        x: numpy array
        dist_method (optional): distance function from scipy.spatial.distance

    Returns: list of distances
    """

    return [dist.dist_method(q, x_i) for x_i in x]

def load_samples():

    x = np.array([[1, 6],[2, 4],[3, 7],[6, 8],[7, 1],[8, 4]])

    y = np.array([[7],[8],[16],[44],[50],[68]])

    q = (4, 2)

    return x, y, q
```

Here's what I'm doing in the interpreter:

```
>>> import KNN as knn
>>> x, y, q = knn.load_samples()
>>> x
array([[1, 6],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 7],
       [6, 8],
       [7, 1],
       [8, 4]])
>>> d = knn.get_distances(q, x, 'cityblock')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "KNN.py", line 19, in get_distances
    return [dist.dist_method(q, x_i) for x_i in x]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dist_method'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with:

```
return [dist.dist_method(q, x_i) for x_i in x]
```

is that your attempting to use `dist_method` to access a function from `dist` whose name matches the value of the string (i.e `"euclidean"`), however `dist.dist_method` will look up a function named `"dist_method"` within the `dist` object, which does not exist.

To access an object's function by name, you would use `getattr`, which will return the object attribute matching the string.

What you want to do is:

```
[getattr(dist,dist_method)(q, x_i) for x_i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheoretiCAL's answer shows you one approach to get desired result and here is another one:

```
methods = {
    'canberra': dist.canberra,
    'euclidean': dist.euclidean,
    # etc
}


def get_distances(q, x, dist_method=None, *args, **kwargs):
    method = methods.get(dist_method, dist.euclidean)
    return [method(q, x_i) for x_i in x]
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that `dist_method` is not the name of anything in the module you're trying to use.  You can use the modules `__dict__` attribute to "fetch" the appropriate method.

```
[dist.__dict__[dist_method](q, x_i) for x_i in x]
```

Comment: @jseery because accessing private attributes and functions is bad practice