# How to improve code and reduce number of code?

Tags: python, pointers, coding-style, refactoring

That code is exactly the same, so I want to refactor it in a simple way to reduce the number of lines. One thing which is different is min/max function execution.
Is it available pointer to function in python to call min/max as a pointer to function like in C?

```
def calculate_min(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    try:
        v = a[e][f]
        b[d] = v if np.isnan(b[d]) else min(b[d], v)    #min()
    except KeyError as exc:
        logger.error("keyerror")

def calculate_max(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    try:
        v = a[e][f]
        b[d] = v if np.isnan(b[d]) else max(b[d], v)    #max()
    except KeyError as exc:
        logger.error("keyerror")
```

Comment: Totally unrelated but you should use `logger.exception()` instead of `logger.error()` => this will add the full error message and traceback to the log, which is _very_ useful for debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An option to reduce duplication would be

```
def calculate_value(a, b, c, d, e, f, func=max):
    try:
        v = a[e][f]
        b[d] = v if np.isnan(b[d]) else func(b[d], v)    #min() or max()
    except KeyError as exc:
        logger.error("keyerror")
```

Depending on the func parameter, you can pass along the `min` or `max` function and get the wanted result. Here is an example on how to pass on functions as arguments : [How do I pass a method as a parameter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just make one function and add an argument that specifies which function to call. For example:

```
def calculate_func(a, b, c, d, e, f, func):
    try:
        v = a[e][f]
        b[d] = v if np.isnan(b[d]) else func(b[d], v)    #replaced min/max by func
    except KeyError as exc:
        logger.error("keyerror")

calculate_min = lambda a, b, c, d, e, f: calculate_func(a, b, c, d, e, f, min)
```