# self.close_application adding "self.close_application()" result in program closed

Tags: python, pyqt4

I would like to know why when I do `btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application())` the program closed instantly. It seems like `self.close_application` executed even though I did not click the print button. However, it works as intended when I use `btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)`.

Can anyone explain to me why using `self.close_applciation()` results in my Q window to be instantly closed without even me clicking the "print" button?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Kenny")

        self.home()
        self.show()

    def home(self):
        self.FullName()
        self.show()

    def FullName(self):
        win = QWidget(self)

        flo=QFormLayout()
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("&Print",self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        flo.addRow(btn ,QPushButton("Cancel"))
        self.setCentralWidget(win)
        win.setLayout(flo)        
        win.show()

    def close_application(self):
        print("Bye Bye")
        sys.exit() 



def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write `btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application())`, `self.close_application()` is executed immediately (and the result of the function would be sent to `btn.clicked.connect`, but at that time the application is already closed).

When you write `btn.clicked.connect(self.close_application)` it is not - because you did not call it.

Instead, this code sends the reference to bound method `self.close_application`, to `btn.clicked.connect`, to be executed when the button is clicked.

---

To compare it with another example:

```
def f():
    print('ffff')
```

calling `f()` prints `ffff`, but just using reference to `f` does not print anything:

```
a = f()  # prints ffff
b = f    # does not print anything

b()      # prints ffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. So you are saying that using `self.close_application()` result in `self.close_application()` to be executed first which result in the window to exit whereas using `self.close_application` result in this function to be executed only when the the button is clicked?

Comment: @meric Yes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706721/1994235) post on Stack Overflow might be of interest to you as it explains how you can pass a reference to a method, to another method (which is what you want to do).