# How to retrieve row from database by matching form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm making an Inventory Management System, which now I'm trying to make my form input more efficient.

I have 2 tables of `Arrival` and `Withdraw`

In table `Arrival` there are `prod_cd` , `prod_nm`, ..., `withdraw`

In table `Withdraw` there are `prod_cd`, `prod_nm`, `withdraw`

I want to make my form only input the `prod_cd` and then the field of `prod_nm` and `withdraw` would automatically retrieved from the `Withdraw` table

I've try to make another page so there will be Inquiry first to retrieve the `Withdraw.objects`, and then Add the record but it throw an error

**views.py**

```
def add_cycle(request, model, cls, inquiry):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = cls(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(inquiry)

    else:
    form = cls()
    return render(request, 'add_new.html', {'form': form})

def add_arrival(request):
    return add_cycle(request, Arrival, ArrivalForm, inquiry_arrival)

def inquiry_cycle(request, pk, model, cls):

    instance= Withdraw.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = cls(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = cls(request.POST,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect ('index')
    else:
        form = ArrivalForm(instance=instance)
    return render_to_response('add_newInquiry.html', {'form': form})

def inquiry_arrival (request, pk):
    return inquiry_cycle(request, pk, Arrival, ArrivalForm)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^add_arrival$', add_arrival, name='add_arrival'),
url(r'^inquiry_arrival$', inquiry_arrival, name='inquiry_arrival'),
```

**forms.py**

```
class ArrivalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Arrival
        fields = ('prod_cd', 'prod_nm', 'quantity', 'issues', 'location', 'withdraw', 'expired_date', 'sup_sheet')
```

**add_new.html**

```
<form method="POST">
    <br>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>ADDING ITEMS</h4>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="id_{{ form.prod_cd.name }}" class="col-2 col-form-label"> {{ form.prod_cd.label }} </label>
        <div class="col-10">
                {{ form.prod_cd }}

        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Inquiry</button>

</form>
```

**add_newInquiry.html**

```
<form method="POST">
    <br>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>ADDING ITEMS</h4>
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="col-2 col-form-label"> {{ field.label }} </label>
        <div class="col-10">
                {{ field }}

        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button"> Add Record</button>

</form>
```

I expect my form would retrieve some of it fields value from database, but I still got an error

```
ValueError at /add_arrival
The view inventory.views.add_arrival didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Replace contents of `add_arrival` function with `add_cycle` and `inquiry_arrival` with `inquiry_cycle`

Comment: @Ahtisham where should I replace it ? views.py ?
Because actually I use the add_cycle and inquiry_cycle to be inherited
There are some other similar function like add_arrival in my views.py

Answer (score 0):

Let's trace the error together! So, `The view inventory.views.add_arrival didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` What this means is that when Django attempts to fetch the *add_arrival* view, no templates are returned.

Let's take a further look at *add_arrival* view. It calls the function *add_cycle*. Pay attention to the last parameter *inquiry_arrival*, which is a method.

Now, in the *add_cycle* function, if the form is valid, we return `redirect(inquiry)` where *inquiry* is the *inquiry_arrival* method. However, since *inquiry* is a method, it needs to be called for something to be returned! To call this method, you should have added brackets behind inquiry, like so: `redirect(inquiry())`. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python) for further information. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try that one.