# Why the key value in sort() can take a custom function address as its parameter?

Tags: python, sorting

Today, I encounter a code slide below and I am confused that why `key=takeSecond` is a valid syntax. I mean, shouldn't it be `key=takeSecond(elem)`? However, the code works perfectly and I don't know why.

```
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# random list
random = [(2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 1), (1, 3)]

# sort list with key
random.sort(key=takeSecond)

# print list
print('Sorted list:', random)
```

Comment: key  takes random as parameter . You should go through object Oriented concepts to understand this.

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html - the key needs to be *callable*, with a single argument.

Comment: No. The key point you are missing is that in Python functions are just like any other object. The can be assigned to a name, `myfunc = takeSecond` and they can be passed as arguments to a function, or returned from a function. Just like `int`,`list`, or what have you. IOW Python has first-class functions

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method takes as `key` parameter the function, you're asking why right?.
So, it's taking a function because if you'll do `takeSecond(elem)` then Python just return the value.

If you implement it in this way:

```
random.sort(key=takeSecond((1, 2)))
```

It's equal to this:

```
random.sort(key=2) # Because the function returns 2 (elem[1]).
```

And it's incorrect.
So you provide to `sort` method the function that he can call it, I'll show you a function that takes another function as argument for better understanding.

Here it is:

```
def get_func(function, values):
    for item in values:
        function(item) # For every item in the list it'll execute this function.
```

So the function receives the function and uses it, equals to how `sort` method uses it.

Answer (score 1):

`takeSecond(elem)` means you're calling the function `takeSecond` with `elem` as a paramter and getting the results back. However if you pass just the function name such as `key=takeSecond` you're passing the function object which can be called by the sort function.

Here is an [in-depth explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706735/13901402)

Comment: Thank you. BTW, when the code run to 'random.sort(key=takeSecond)'，and the takesecond() is invoked. How can the interpreter know which argument should be passed to takesecond()? Or the method sort() take the elements of the list 'random' as arguments by default?

Answer (score 0):

With the `key` argument you specify the function that *will be called with each element of the list being sorted*. Specifying such a function is useful when the list's elements are structured as in your case and you want to sort based on a certain component of that structure.

If you were to specify `key=taksecond(elem)`, `takesecond(elem)` is an immediate call to your function with argument `elem` (which happens to be undefined; it is only defined *in* the function `takesecond` when the passed argument is bound to the name `elem`) and that surely would only be correct if the returned value from that call happened to be a function to be used for comparing the keys.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain 'it is only defined in the function takesecond when the passed argument is bound to the name elem' futher? I don't quite catch that.

Comment: If you tried to sort with `random.sort(key=takeSecond(elem)`, you would get an error because `elem` is not defined at the point *where you are calling `takeSecond`*. `elem` is, however, defined *in* function `takeSecond`: it is the name of the formal argument being passed to that function.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter of  `list.sort()` can take in function which returns a value. It compares these values against each other to sort the content

```
def takeSecond(elem):
   return elem[1]
```

Each parameter of the list will be passed into the `takeSecond()` function, something like this

```
 # takeSecond((2, 2)),   #first  return 2
 # takeSecond((3, 4)),   #second return 4
 # takeSecond((4, 1)),   #third  return 1
 # takeSecond((1, 3)).   #fouth  return 3
```

so the `sort` function is comparing `2, 4, 1, 3` which be be used to position the resulting element in the list

Answer (score -2):

For list, python has the method  `list.sort(key=None, reverse=False)`, that sort list by which `key`

You can check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)