# Attribute error: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'clear_Entry'

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a calculator app in Python.

I am using a Jupyter notebook, and this is the error I run into:

```
AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'clear_Entry'
```

And this is the code that causes this error:

```
btnClear = Button(
    innerFrame,
    text='C',
    width=6,
    height=2,
    font=('arial',18,'bold'),
    bd=7,
    bg='gainsboro',
    command=added_value.clear_Entry)
```

Here is the `clear_Entry` method I defined:

```
        def clear_Entry(self):
            self.result=False
            self.current='0'
            self.input_value= True
            self.display(0)
```

Comment: I need help from an Professional.

Comment: Hey there Zafeer, if you need help, please be sure to properly format your question and please include a minimal reproducible example of your problem _that led you to the error you posted_. Tell us a bit more about your environment as well.

Comment: I am trying to make a calculater

Comment: I am doing this in the environment of Anaconda jupyter notebook

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere, can you please post here a link to your notebook?
Or perhaps just the problematic chunk of code that's causing this error?
By the looks of it, you are attempting to access a property called `clear_Entry` on a `Calc` object, which is missing. Please check that you don't have a typo in `clear_Entry` or something of that sort.

Comment: I have check it many times but every time the results were same

Comment: The notebook you posted is running on your local machine, not a public Jupyter notebook, so a link won't work here - you can remove it and your comment. Please take a look at my answer for more information on your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706721/how-do-i-pass-a-method-as-a-parameter-in-python) StackOverflow question, more specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842803/4814251) answer.

You are attempting to pass a method of the `Calc` object as an argument to the `Button` class constructor, and for some reason the `added_value` variable which contains a `Calc` object does not have the `clear_Entry` method on it - this is the meaning of the missing attribute error you're seeing.

Try to run a check *before* accessing this property that it does exist, and please look at the question I added for more information.

Also, make sure that you don't have an error, and that the `clear_Entry` method is defined **inside** the `Calc` class.

Comment: It is giving AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'clear_Entry' error regards to this line of code command= added_value.clear_Entry)